# Moved Database to a new server now entity website doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We moved the database 2008 to 2012 and moved it to a new server.

Now when running the website I get the following error:

> The model backing the 'DocumentDBContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

I have gone through several of the similar answers but none seem to work.

No changes were made to any of the tables so the tables should match the models 100%.

What is the quickest way to get this to start working again?

I am using Entity Framework 5.0

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this message several times. And it exactly means that the database changed. Run `Update-Database -Verbose` (and optionally `-Force` switch) to update the database. This worked for me every time.

For more info see here: [Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ591621.aspx#enabling)

Comment: I run Update-Database -Verbose and it says it will not continue because of Dataloss.  The database tables haven't changed.  All we did was take our working database and moved it to 2012.  Tables columns data is all the same.  Will -Force delete data?

Comment: If it says will result in data loss it means that database **has** changed. You can use the `-Force` switch to force database update. You must have changed something minor (made a column nullable for e.g.)

Comment: How can I see what it changed then?  Because being the only developer for the website here and knowing I have not made any changes to it.  I need to see what changes it is thinking were made.  Is that possible?

Comment: You could change `Initial Catalog` in connection string to make it create a new updated database and see if it's any different. Also, when you run `Update-Database -Verbose` (with `-Force` in your case) the powershell prompt will show SQL being issued to the database (so you'll see the `ALTER TABLE` statements).

Comment: (Yes, `-Force` might delete data if you dropped a column for example. Or it might be just a warning, if for example you changed column from `nvarchar(max)` to `nvarchar(500)` it might truncate data.)

Comment: I used -Script to see what sql it was changing.  And it was only trying to get rid of all of our Development site tables.  So upon further investigation it appears our Developement Database was corrupt and will need to be re-copied over because the live site now works.